# Setting debug = False makes the Django app crash with the following error, how to fix it?

Tags: python, django, debugging, heroku, django-oscar

It gives: **internal server error**
when I try to acces the site/admin or any other app
Trying to deploy my app using heroku.

**THis is the log from the heroku:**

> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 125, in __cast
>   2019-05-08T15:15:47.484058+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.__text_cast()
>
> 2019-05-08T15:15:47.484060+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 113, in __text_cast
>
> 2019-05-08T15:15:47.484061+00:00 app[web.1]:     return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
>
> 2019-05-08T15:15:47.484063+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 86, in reverse
>
> 2019-05-08T15:15:47.484064+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
>
> 2019-05-08T15:15:47.484066+00:00 app[web.1]: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'promotions' is not a registered namespace
>
> 2019-05-08T15:15:47.484067+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.251.26 - - [08/May/2019:15:15:47 +0000] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "-"
>
> 2019-05-08T15:17:06.098441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=aapnik123.herokuapp.com request_id=18244196-eaec-43ef-be28-bb4cbbdee0b0 fwd="103.232.241.185" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=7368 protocol=https
>
> 2019-05-08T15:17:06.098037+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.174.177 - - [08/May/2019:15:17:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6967 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"
>
> 2019-05-08T15:19:19.758608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/" host=aapnik123.herokuapp.com request_id=17fea225-3ad5-4ec5-b817-e941818ea8d7 fwd="103.232.241.185" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=302 bytes=346 protocol=https
>
> 2019-05-08T15:19:19.759552+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.123.204.200 - - [08/May/2019:15:19:19 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"

I have tried setting allowed hosts = "*" .

**this is my url.py in the main app**
I have tried using namepsace for resolving the **NoReverseMatch** error butit does not work.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from oscarapi.app import application
# from getdetail import *
# app_name = "eshop"
urlpatterns = [

    # path('i18n',django.conf.urls.i18n),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # ath('dashboard/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('GET_DET/', include('GET_DETAIL.urls',namespace='GET_DET')),
    # path('PUT_DET/', include('PUT_DET.urls',namespace='PUT_DET')),
    path('GET_DET/', include('GET_DETAIL.urls')),
    path('PUT_DET/', include('PUT_DET.urls')),
    # path('oscarapi/', application.urls),
    path('', application.urls),

]
```

Comment: does your login.html page template have a `{% url %}` somewhere?

Comment: I don't have a login.html page

Comment: show the entire stack trace for that specific request

Comment: Without the full stack trace this is an unsolvable mystery. You can try putting `debug=True` & then getting the error traceback & putting it here. If that isn't giving you errors then it's likely some setting that is dependent on `debug=False`, so you'll need to include that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is solved. Turns out I had not set up the database on heroku, just did it locally.
So it was working locally but failed in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is worked for me with set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` in settings.py

Comment: was the debug = true or false?

Comment: There was debug = false